# Play 2 framework: abstract model class

Tags: java, database, inheritance, playframework-2.0

I am implemention `Item` and `User` relation in the following way. Now I need to have different relations for the same pair of item and user. So I am considering another class `ItemUser2`. Probably I would need `ItemUserBase` and from it extend `ItemUser1` and `ItemUser2` and so on. If `ItemUserBase` extends `Model` then some extract table would be created in the database, but `ItemUserBase` is supposed to be kind of abstract. **What do you think?**

**Would it affect the joining annotations in some way to assure correctness?**

Item.java

```
@Entity
public class Item extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    public List<UserItem> userItems = new ArrayList<UserItem>();
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="item")
    public List<UserItem> userItems = new ArrayList<UserItem>();
}
```

UserItem.java

```
@Entity
public class UserItem extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    public User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item")
    public Item item;

    public Date date;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works that way actually. I am going to keep the code for later readers.